# Special characters in c.draw "text" with mini_magick (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, minimagick

I am having quite a bit of trouble getting mini_magick to draw text that contains quotes, double quotes, etc. on an image. I have tried various modifications on `c.draw` to no avail. What is the best way to escape these characters so that c.draw will display them without an error?

error: `non-conforming drawing primitive definition`m'`

produced by

```
 c.draw "text 8,8 'I'm'"
```

Including other special character such as é will result in an error as well. I would like to be able to accept text strings from users as input, therefore the need for Unicode compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see...

- ...these usage examples [**"Drawing Special Characters in the Text String"**](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#text) and
- ...this forum thread: [**"Trouble with quotes in Bash scripts"**](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=20787&start=0)

?

In any case, the following works for me on the commandline:

```
convert \
   -size 500x100 xc:none \
   -box yellow \
   -pointsize 72 \
   -gravity center \
   -draw "text 8,8 '  \'I\'m\'  '" \
   -trim \
   +repage \
    special-chars.png
```

and produces this:
[image: Example PNG showing special characters created with ImageMagicks text drawing function]

For more complicated text drawing requirements, you are strongly advised to circumvent all the escaping by writing your drawing commands into a separate `*.mvg` ([Magick Vector Graphic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-vector-graphics.php)) file. For example with this content in `1.mvg`:

```
 text 8,8 "öäü ß ÄÖÜ é"
```

and this command:

```
convert \
   -size 250x100 xc:none \
   -box yellow \
   -pointsize 72 \
   -gravity center \
   -draw @1.mvg \
   -trim \
   +repage \
    special-chars.png
```

you'll get
[image: More special characters via an .mvg file]

Or even, with `2.mvg`:

```
push graphic-context
 viewbox 0 0 600 100
 push graphic-context
   fill 'orange'
   rectangle 0,0 600,100
 pop graphic-context
 push graphic-context
   fill 'white'
   font Palatino-Roman
   font-size 48
   stroke-width 2
   gravity SouthEast
   text 8,8 "äöü ß ÄÖÜ é"
 pop graphic-context
 push graphic-context
   fill 'green'
   rectangle 10,10 300,90
 pop graphic-context
 push graphic-context
   fill 'red'
   font Palatino-Bold-Italic
   font-size 28
   stroke-width 1
   text 18,40 "€ ¥ © ℉ ậ ḁ å ǎ à ç ë ĵ"
 pop graphic-context
pop graphic-context
```

and this command:

```
convert 2.mvg 2.png
```

you can get:
[image: ...and even more special characters]

Comment: You are right, you can escape this, but try it with é or an umlaut. I am looking for it to work on unicode chars in general since I will be using user input directly.

Comment: Ok, I answered your question. How about an upvote now? If you're not asking precisely the right question, you'll not be getting fully satisfying answers....

Comment: No problem, my friend. Just woke up. I would like to avoid conversion like this since the code will be called from a web app. This will give some context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917561/unicode-characters-render-with-rmagick-but-not-with-minimagick

Comment: @JacksonHenley: I'm not familiar with minimagick, but the same trick as works for the direct `convert` commandline (temporarily putting all text into a `file.mvg` and then use this file on the commandline via `-draw @file.mvg` should also work for minimagick...

Answer (score 0):

```
#Try lightweight GD2: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?q=GD2


require 'gd2-ffij'
PATH_TO_FONT   = "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/DroidSans.ttf"
    image = GD2::Image::TrueColor.new(512, 512)
    image.draw do |pen|
      pen.font = GD2::Font::TrueType[PATH_TO_FONT, 32]
      pen.color = image.palette.resolve(GD2::Color[128, 16, 16])
      pen.move_to(256, 128)
      pen.text(GD2::VERSION, 5)
    end
image.export('./one.jpg')
```